# Create connection string for Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need bild connecting string for connect to MS SQL Server. 
The finished line looks like this:

```
Data Source=MACHINE-VOIV7EH\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog = OptiSoft; Persist Security Info = False;Integrated Security=True;
```

But when a string is built from elements, the connection will fail.

```
 string ConectString= "Data Source=" + ServerName.Trim() + "; Initial Catalog = " + Database.Trim() + "; Persist Security Info = False;Integrated Security=True;";
```

The strings are exactly the same!

Comment: And what exact exception are you getting?

Comment: There is a `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` class to do this for you

Answer (score 1):

As suggested it is better to use the SQLConnectionStringBuilder class for this purpose.

[As per the documentation:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder?view=netframework-4.8)

"The connection string builder lets developers programmatically create syntactically correct connection strings, and parse and rebuild existing connection strings, using properties and methods of the class.

The connection string builder provides strongly typed properties corresponding to the known key/value pairs allowed by SQL Server. Developers needing to create connection strings as part of applications can use the SqlConnectionStringBuilder class to build and modify connection strings."

Also it does reduce any errors you might encounter when trying to create connection strings dynamically from within your application.

```
var builder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            DataSource = "MACHINE - VOIV7EH\\SQLEXPRESS",
            InitialCatalog = "Optisoft",
            PersistSecurityInfo = false,
            IntegratedSecurity = true

        };
```